# INSERT and UPDATE data on Remote Server table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am trying to insert and update data on a remote server table. I don't want to create a linked server connection. Below is what I want to have. Can someone please suggest how I can achieve this? I am using SQL Server 2008.

```
SELECT * 
INTO OPENROWSET ('SQLOLEDB', 'tstapp01';'sa';'*****',
                 'SELECT * INTO table1 FROM OPENROWSET(''''SQLOLEDB'''',''''172.29.211.12'''';''''sa'''';''''*****'''', ''''Select * from [databasename].dbo.[table2] with (nolock) '''')'''
) 

UPDATE OPENROWSET('SQLOLEDB', 'tstapp01';'sa';'*****',
                  'UPDATE database1.dbo.[table1] SET [column1] = s.[column1], [column2] = s.[column2] FROM database1.dbo.table2 s WITH (nolock) INNER JOIN database1.dbo.[table2] t WITH (nolock) ON s.condition = t.condition OPTION (MAXDOP 1) ')
```

Thanks

Comment: If this is going to get called a lot and maybe become more complex, another option would be SSIS

Comment: Did you read this?  https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/415666/OpenRowSet-Without-linking-servers